# Remove <Done> Button in Keypad IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I have a UITextField and while typing on the normal keyboard there is a  button showing on the menu bar above the keyboard. I want to remove the  button.

How can I do this?

Comment: before post search SOF there are most of the answers available for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `Storyboard`, select `TextField`, choose `Attributes Inspector`.
Then under `Return Key` you can adjust the type of the button.

[image]

As for deleting it, you would may disable it, or if you want it to completely disappear, the easiest (though perhaps not the best) way would be to put an overlay on it (for example a view at appropriate coordinates when the keyboard is visible.